# Detect any character other than int

Tags: c

AIM: When I enter any numerical value other than the choices, I get the invalid input message. But when I enter any char value like a-z or *(#$ characters the program loops infinitely. Please help! Need to fix the little problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
 int ch,end=0;
 while(end!=1)
{
 printf("\t MENU! \n");
 printf("\n1 - Set\n");
 printf("2 - Start\n");
 printf("3 - About\n");
 printf("4 - Exit\n");
 printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
 scanf("%d",&ch);

 if(ch==1)
     {
     printf("\nYella\n");
     }

 else if(ch==2)    
  { 
   printf("\nFella\n");
  }   

else if(ch==3)
 {
 printf("\nMella\n");
 }

else if(ch==4)
 {
 exit(0);
 }

 else
 {
 printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n");
 printf("\n");
 }
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: If the input contains letters, the `scanf` doesn't consume it, so it remains in the input buffer, and `scanf("%d",...)` still fails on the non-digit (non-minus). Clear the buffer after a failed `scanf`. Or don't use `scanf` at all, `getchar()` or `fgets` are easy alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this because the

```
scanf("%d",&ch);
```

is waiting integer and you have entered non numeric characters so you will get infinite loop. to fix it change it with

```
while (scanf(" %d",&ch)<1 || ch>4 || ch<1) {
   printf("Your input is wrong. Please enter your choice again:");
   scanf("%*s"); // this scanf allow to clean your stdin
};
```

and add a space at the beginning of the format `"%d"` in order to avoid the newline problems.

It should be `" %d"`

Adding the check `|| ch>4 || ch<1` will allow to check that the input integer is between 1 and 4.

Comment: you can even add a check that the ch is between 0 and 4 . I wil update my answer

Comment: Alright! Never seen a neat reply in my life like this before.

Comment: The space before the `%d` is unnecessary, only `%c` and `%[` directives do not skip initial whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the data is of an invalid type. Simply change the input type to `char` to avoid this issue. This should work for you:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int end=0;
    while(end!=1)
    {
        printf(" MENU! \n");
        printf("\n1 - Set\n");
        printf("2 - Start\n");
        printf("3 - About\n");
        printf("4 - Exit\n");
        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%c",&ch);

        if(ch=='1')
            printf("\nYella\n");
        else if(ch=='2')
            printf("\nFella\n");
        else if(ch=='3')
            printf("\nMella\n");
        else if(ch=='4')
            exit(0);
        else
            printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n\n");

        /*
        //Or better yet,
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1':
            {
                printf("\nYella\n");
                break;
            }
            case '2':
            {
                printf("\nFella\n");
                break;
            }
            case '3':
            {
                printf("\nMella\n");
                break;
            }
            case '4':
            {
                exit(0);
                //break not required
            }
            default:
                printf("\nInvalid Input. Please try again.\n\n");
        }
        */
    }
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```